# Does YouTube Data API V3 work with YouTube Music?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I would like to extract playlist data from Youtube Music, as well as metadata related to the songs in the said playlist. Is this possible with the Youtube Data V3 API, or YouTube Analytics API?

If so, where can I find documentation about calls and available metadata; I am not finding what I need on the YouTube Data API page. I am currently referencing PlaylistItems and Playlists in the reference Docs, but it seems that is geared to videos. Is that by design because you can toggle between video and audio in YT Music?

If possible is there an official Rust Crate?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this feature is missing from YouTube Data API and quite a few other API users expressed the same need as yours.

The official [Google staff account](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181347378#comment2) says the following:

> This type of information is not available in the API. We have already raised a feature request for this but I can't guarantee that this feature will be implemented.

That is it: they may well implement this feature at some point, but, unfortunately, cannot tell when that'll happen.